# Clean URL in CakePHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I need help with a clean URL in CakePHP. I've been trying for a while with no luck.

This is the existing htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This is the URL that I'm trying to clean up:

http://example.com/signup/?key=dT33Y%2FeKXCjgeo69XpTs39YV%2F4ZnHht0M5E%2BXk9iDKQ%3D

I would like the URL to look like this:

http://example.com/signup/dT33Y%2FeKXCjgeo69XpTs39YV%2F4ZnHht0M5E%2BXk9iDKQ%3D

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in `/signup/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /signup/\?key=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?key=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting the same url. Could it be that I'm updating the wrong htaccess? I'm editing one in /app/webroot/.

Comment: Ok try this updated code. Is `signup` being served by cakephp?

Comment: Yes, signup is being served by cakephp. I have a controller and view for that dir. Still no luck  :/

Comment: So you can still access `http://example.com/signup/?key=dT33Y%2FeKXCjgeo69XpTs39YV%2F4ZnHht0M5E%2BXk9iDKQ%3D` without any issues?

Comment: Yes, I can get to that url just fine.

Comment: Still no luck. The updated code gave me`http://example.com/home1/myuser/public_html/demo/app/webroot/signup/0lj%2FK5aRN%2FqfcMbM%2B8VY3q%2B0%2FmFO4L09HHjKa50pim8%3D`.

After changing THE_REQUEST to HTTP_HOST, I was still getting `http://example.com/signup/?key=dT33Y%2FeKXCjgeo69XpTs39YV%2F4ZnHht0M5E%2BXk9iDKQ%3D`

Comment: I still see `http://example.com/signup/?key=dT33Y%2FeKXCjgeo69XpTs39YV%2F4ZnHht0M5E%2BXk9iDKQ%3D`

Comment: But previously you said you're getting `http://example.com/home1/myuser/public_html/demo/app/webroot/signup/0lj%2FK5aRN%2FqfcMbM%2B8VY3q%2B0%2FmFO4L09HHjKa50pim8%3D` so rule was working but because it had missing `/` before `signup` you got that path. So I just made it to `/signup/%1`.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm still getting `http://example.com/signup/?key=dT33Y%2FeKXCjgeo69XpTs39YV%2F4ZnHht0M5E%2BXk9iDK‌​Q%3D`.

I would like to remove `?key=`

Comment: Is `/signup` a directory? Are there more rules in this .htaccess? Are there any other .htaccess there?

Comment: Yes, /signup is a directory. Your code is the only thing in the htaccess file. The htaccess file resides at `/home1/myuser/public_html/demo/app/webroot`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45779/discussion-between-defendog-and-anubhava)